# PHP Undefined index in array structure

Tags: php

I have array structure like this inside variable $theArray :

```
Array
(
    [name] => Me1
    [email] => me_1@email.com
    [week2018012920180204] => Approved
    [week2018020520180211] => Approved
    [week2018021220180218] => Approved
    [week2018021920180225] => Approved
    [week2018022620180304] => Approved
    [data] => 5
)

Array
(
    [name] => Me2
    [email] => me_2@email.com
    [week2018012920180204] => Approved
    [week2018020520180211] => Approved
    [week2018021220180218] => Approved
    [week2018021920180225] => Approved
    [week2018022620180304] => Approved
    [data] => 5
)
```

But when I tried to loop to get value, through this code :

```
foreach ($theArray as $key => $val)
{
   print_r($val['week2018012920180204'])
}
```

It always throws an error:

> Undefined index: week2018012920180204

When I am try to get other value from name, email, or data is always success without error.

Please any advice about my problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, please post the result of `print_r($theArray)`

Comment: Or post more complete and relevant code instead of bits and pieces

Comment: What do you think `foreach ($arr as $key=>$val)` does? Can you explain what would be in `$val` when you run that? (because if this is normal code, `$key` will already be `week2018012920180204` at some point, with `$val` will be the associated value)

Comment: You showed us two print_r dumps instead of one for $theArray. I don't think it's an array containing records like you think it is. As of now, you should be able to do `print_r($theArray ['week2018012920180204']);`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I might be wrong, but I read the question as `$theArray` being a multidimensional array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I read it as "there is not enough information to decide one way or another" so we'll have to wait for an edit/comment by Arizto.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I read that as well... :-)

Comment: because '$val' is not an array

Comment: As you can see from the comments, we don't know if your array examples are two different dumps of `$theArray` contains both arrays. You need to update your question and explain the situation or any "answer" will simply be guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is looks incorrect. 
If your array is like this you can get results like this,

```
<?php
$theArray = array
(
    "name" => "Me1",
    "email" => "me_1@email.com",
    "week2018012920180204" => "Approved",
    "week2018020520180211" => "Approved",
    "week2018021220180218"=> "Approved",
    "week2018021920180225" => "Approved",
    "week2018022620180304" => "Approved",
    "data" => 5
);
print_r($theArray['week2018012920180204']);

?>
```

But if your array is like this, you can get results like this,

```
<?php
$theArray = array
(
    array(
        "name" => "Me1",
        "email" => "me_1@email.com",
        "week2018012920180204" => "Approved",
        "week2018020520180211" => "Approved",
        "week2018021220180218"=> "Approved",
        "week2018021920180225" => "Approved",
        "week2018022620180304" => "Approved",
        "data" => 5
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Me2",
        "email" => "me_2@email.com",
        "week2018012920180204" => "Approved",
        "week2018020520180211" => "Approved",
        "week2018021220180218" => "Approved",
        "week2018021920180225" => "Approved",
        "week2018022620180304" => "Approved",
        "data" => 5
    )
);

foreach ($theArray as $arr)
{
   print_r($arr['week2018012920180204']."<br/> \n");
}
?>
```